# How do I display the intersection of commits between two branches in git log?

Tags: git, git-log

I have a *main* branch as the root. Depending on the minor version, I create branches in the dev family, such as *dev/2.3, dev/2.4, dev/2.5, dev/2.6*.
Currently, *dev/2.6* is the active branch for development.

For a specific task, I branch off from *dev/2.6* and work, for example, in *tasks/task1*. I make commits and push them to the remote tasks/task1 branch. Afterward, I create a pull request from *tasks/task1* to *dev/2.6*. Then, after some time, I create a pull request from *dev/2.6* to *main*.

My question is whether it's possible, after merging *dev/2.6* into *main* via a pull request, to use the

```
git log
```

command to find the intersection of commits between *dev/2.6* and *main*?

For instance, I tried

```
git --no-pager log --oneline main..dev/2.6,
```

but this command only shows the differences in commits. What I need is to log all the commits made in *dev/2.6* that are present in main but not in *dev/2.4*, *dev/2.5*, and so on.
**Is there a git log syntax for displaying the output of a list of commits exist only in dev/2.6 and main??**

Thank you advance

Comment: If you've merged `dev/2.5` _etc._ into `main` previously, then its commits **are** on both `dev/2.6` and `main`.

Comment: got it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't exactly get that because if you've merged them together then everything in `dev/2.6` is in `master` ( but not everything in master is in `dev/2.6`)

The usual thing I can think of that is close to what you want is 'what did `dev/2.6` add since our last release.  If you had tagged that release with a version tag this would be even easier.

Here are some ways I can think of that try to get to what you wanted:

In short:
`git log main dev/2.6`
but likely better done with
`git log --graph --abbrev-commit --decorate --date=short main dev/2.6`
or whatever log mechanism you prefer.

This says to log both `main` and `dev/2.6` together so you will see where they diverge and where they merge together and if they diverge after that.

A better thing I would think of using is `git shortlog dev/2.6 ^dev/2.5` or `git shortlog dev/2.6 ^origin/master`  or replace origin/master with the fork point where `dev/2.6` broke off from.  Which would show you whats on `dev/2.6` that wasn't on `dev/2.5` or `master` respectively.

This really breaks down if you merge `master` into those branches multiple times or those branches were merged multiple times back to master.   Which is why I take tags when using a flow like this, when I merge `dev/2.6` back to `master` I would tag that commit as `v2.6.1` and if I merged again `v2.6.2` etc.   in this way I can do `git short-log`s between the current state or tag and the prior tag to see what was added.

Comment: In general, I accept the answer that in this case.
 I will use "git log dev/2.6 ^dev/2.5" as a more optimal solution. 
If I understand correctly, what is pushed from dev/2.6, dev/2.5, dev/2.4, and so on into main automatically becomes part of main, and there is no segregation of data within main. I just thought that there might be some internal separation of influences from dev/2.5 and dev/2.6, for example.